# Can an adjective modify a na-adjective?

Tags: syntax, adjectives

I assumed not, but I saw

> 言い知れぬ甘美なもの

Translated as **"something inexpressibly sweet"**, as if 言い知れぬ modified 甘美な. Is it just a quirk of translation and both　the adjective 言い知れぬ and 形容動詞 modify もの (that is, lit: something inexpressible and sweet), or does 言い知れぬ modify 形容動詞 here somehow?

Comment: I changed the question, feel free to edit it but I'm not familiar with the term 連体詞 and I don't know if it modifies other 品詞　any different from 形容詞 (does it?)　so I hesitated to add it.

Comment: That's okay.  It looks like an answer will have to address your notion of adjective anyway, so we might as well leave that part of the question the way it is :-)

Answer (score 5):

言い知れぬ is an expression that is used like an adjective, but is actually a **negative verb**. Basically, it's an archaic way of saying 言い知れない. In this case, don't think of 言い知れぬ as modifying the na-adjective. Think of it as modifying the noun which has already been modified by the na-adjective. The "sweetness" isn't what's indescribable; the "sweet thing" is.